# Loading a session variable before UI construction

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a session variable that is needed to filter my JPA query as follows:

```
activities = JPAContainerFactory.make(ActivityEntity.class, DCSAdminUI.PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
activities.addContainerFilter(new Compare.Equal("organisation.rowid", OrgID));
```

My view is able to receive the session variable in the `enter()` method as follows:

```
@Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

        OrgID = (String) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().getAttribute("org");
        buildLayout();

    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to take the variable from the `enter()` method and use it in constructing the UI. As you can see from the `enter()` method code above, I am manually calling `buildLayout()` which does the UI construction. This works but I end up getting the view re-constructed within itself every time I navigate to another view and back to this one. I know that `enter()` is called before the constructor but what I don't understand is why the constructor doesn't seem to be called unless I explicitly call it in the `enter()` method

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated

Comment: Careful with the terminology, "constructor" has a very specific meaning in Java land. I assume with "constructor" you are referring to that buildLayout() method here, and not the constructor of some class.

Comment: By "constructor" I meant the actual constructor because I have tried using the manual `buildLayout()` method and also tried loading the variable directly into the constructor (with no `buildLayout()` method) based on what I've read that the constructor is automatically called after the `enter()` method. If I'm wrong then you are right and I do need to be careful with the terminology!

Comment: Okay, so you are talking about an actual constructor. Alas you apparently can't be specific about which constructor exactly you are talking about. Constructors don't get called by frameworks or code, they get invoked by the JVM under water when a new instance of an object is created. If you are talking about the constructr of the class that this enter() method is part of then it is most definitely invoked BEFORE the call to enter(), not after.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your view class is actually called either by you when you add your views to the navigator or by the framework when you are navigating to the view. This depends on which overloaded variant of `Navigator#addView()` you use.

Judging by your question, I assume you want to avoid that each time you visit the view either a JPA query is executed or some form of recursive UI construction (whatever you mean by 'constructed within itself') is performed.

A way better approach for your problem, however, would be if you separated your UI code from its data logic. That is, keep the data (JPAContainer) out of the view altogether. Then, you could construct the UI in your `View`'s default constructor (use `Navigator#addView(String, Class<? extends View>)` in that case). You should have a look at the [Model-View-Presenter design pattern](https://vaadin.com/web/magi/home/-/blogs/model-view-presenter-pattern-with-vaadin) to get an idea of how to achieve this separation of concerns. Reading the session variable `OrgID` would then happen in the presenter.

It is better to rebuild the UI upon navigating to a particular view anyway. Rebuilding a Vaadin UI is fast, whereas keeping UI components not currently visible in the browser in the session will waste precious server-side memory. You should keep your session size as small as possible to allow more simultaneous users on the server. That is, only keep components in the session that are actually visible to the user.